# Facebook Conversion API NOT receiving event

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to run a test event in Graph API explorer before integrating it to our website.

I'm having a problem not receiving the test event but the response is not showing any error.

```
{
  "data": [{
    "event_name": "PageView",
    "event_time": 1611631182,
    "action_source": "website",
    "event_source_url": "https://example.com",
    "user_data": {
      "client_ip_address": "1.2.3.4",
      "client_user_agent": "test ua"
    }
  }],
  "test_event_code": "TEST12345"
}
```

I try to include the Email (**em**) parameter inside the **user_data** with the value that is generated by default in Payload Helper. It works fine. But when I generate a different email hash, it's **NOT** working.

I'm using **v9.0** in the API. I hope some could help me solve the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same problem, did you figure it out?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: facing same issue. o.o

Comment: any update sir @CaioCésarP.Ricciuti ?

Comment: Hey @GigaByte, I found out that graph API v10 asks for user_agent and useriP only then you'll get data from the API

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the user data in your payload needs to contain "real" data.

In your example, try using a real `client_user_agent` value (like the one below).

Alternatively, are you certain that you're hashing the email correctly? Compare your email hash against [a SHA256 hash from this website](https://passwordsgenerator.net/sha256-hash-generator/) to ensure you're hashing it correctly.

For example, if you're using JavaScript's `crypto` library to do the SHA256 hash, you need to use `hex` encoding, not `base64` encoding:

```js
crypto.createHash("sha256").update("email@example.com").digest("hex");
```

In my case, the events weren't appearing because I hadn't included IP address & user agent in the payload OR I had included the right fields but set an invalid user agent.

This payload works for me:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "event_name": "TestEvent",
      "event_time": 1627574182,
      "action_source": "email",
      "user_data": {
        "em": "f660ab912ec121d1b1e928a0bb4bc61b15f5ad44d5efdc4e1c92a25e99b8e44a",
        "client_ip_address": "254.254.254.254",
        "client_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0"
      }
    }
  ],
  "test_event_code": "TEST43514"
}
```

**Note: you'll need to update the `test_event_code` and `event_time` fields** (because  the Conversions API only accepts events sent in the last 7 days)

Credit to Matěj's answer on [the Facebook Developers Community forums](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/841431599821194/) for providing a working example payload and the insight into providing real data

Answer (score 0):

I broke my head with this for quite some time, I ended up sending the `Fbp` cookie in mine and the cAPI tests began picking up these requests.

I am actually doing pure offline events so the only parameter I'm sending across is the `fbp` parameter, `action_source = other`, `event_name` and `event_time`

Hopefully this helps someone!